# Date Field - Data Annotation - Not Validating

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

In one of the ViewModels I have, there is a property of type IList, where EmploymentViewModel has some properties two of them are Date properties "From" & "To"

```
    [Display(Name = "From", Description = "Enter your Employment Start Date")]
    [Date(ErrorMessage = "Date selected is invalid"), DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "To", Description = "Enter your Employment End Date")]
    [Date(ErrorMessage = "Date selected is invalid"), DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
```

I am using DataAnnotationExtensions btw.

On the interface, I am using jQuery UI datepicker to allow user to select date. The fields "To" and "From" are not showing any "data-val" attributes despite the DataAnnotations placed.

When I change the date displayed to an invalid date, jQuery unobtrusive validation is not firing a message mentioning that the "Date selected is invalid".

**UPDATED - MORE INFO**

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Employments[i].From, new { @class = "formLabel" })    
@Html.TextBox(GetInputName(i, "From"), (@Model.Employments[i].From.HasValue ? @Model.Employments[i].From.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : ""), new { @class = "textBox toDate dynHasDatepicker", placeholder = "mm/dd/yyyy" })
```

The same View/ViewModel used for another property "BirthDate" works perfect!

There is only one difference in here, the main ViewModel contains two properties:
1- BirthDate
2- Employment (A collection of EmploymentViewModel)

The EmploymentViewModel contains the From and To properties. Does this affect the validation process?

Any reason why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one of two reasons. 1) You have Html.EnableClientScript(false) on the page or 2) You need to use the strongly typed version of Html.TextBox, ie. Html.TextBoxFor. In that case you probably want to look at using Html.BeginCollectionItem, something like this: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/